# how to run an asp.net solution in vscode?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I've created an `Asp.Net` project on visual studio (windows) and I want to make some changes and run the solution on VScode for Mac... can I do that? I have installed .net and stuff. I have tried typing my app path on `launch.json` file:

`"program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/myproject.dll"`,

but is not working. I know this may be a quite silly question but I have been trying to do this since 2 days ago and run in a little stressed.

Comment: Please check [Build an ASP.NET Core app on a Mac or Linux using Visual Studio Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/your-first-mac-aspnet).

Comment: Thank u, I'll check it out

Comment: @csharpbd link is down

Comment: @vaditaslim thanks for the information. Please check the links below.


[Using .NET Core in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/dotnet)

[Get started with .NET Core on macOS using Visual Studio for Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/using-on-mac-vs)